# Option-like behaviour of momentum strategy

Tags: options, equities, portfolio-optimization, asset-pricing, momentum

this may come as rather vague question, since I do not have something very exact issue on my mind. Nevertheless, I think this is an interesting question and must have been thought by some other people as well.

I was reading a paper called "Momentum crashes" by Daniel & Moskowitz (2016) [(link)](https://business.columbia.edu/faculty/research/momentum-crashes), and they describe the pay-offs of zero-investment long-short momentum strategy *in bear markets* analoguous to selling call options on stock market itself. Profits are consistent as far as the market does not rise rapidly under bear markets, destroying the returns of short-leg of the zero-investment portfolio.

Since this short-leg of the portfolio is the one driving the *momentum crashes*, and thus the hefty downside of the momentum portfolio, I would like to understand it a bit better, especially the short call properties, for example could I map (the short-leg) of the momentum to the option greeks to create some sort  of volatility surfaces?

For example, it would be interesting to charectize the payout profile of the short-leg or understand the always difficult timing properties of it. Also, if the short-leg acts like a short call (under bear markets), could it be somehow be translated to a covered call, i.e., could the underlying (short-leg of momentum portfolio) be somehow (timely) bought or replicated?

The paper by Daniel & Moskowitz covers dynamic hedging strategy to mitigate the bear market issue via volatility estimates. There are also papers about residual momentum (Residual momentum by Blitz et al. 2011 ([link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2319861))) which try to develop strategies to deal with the crashiness of momentum.

If anyone has any ideas or papers to refer to which cover the short-leg of the momentum portfolio, and especially the option idea (lend some tools from derivatives to equity trading strategies), I would be happy to hear.